# Stuck on GRUB Bootloader

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I recently had a dual boot setup on my laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. I started having [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144296/how-can-i-safely-delete-kde-plasma) with Ubuntu, and as was suggested to me, I decided to delete Ubuntu and then reinstall it.

In the "create and format hard disk partitions" application on Windows, I deleted the Ubuntu partition. I did not think it was necessary to delete GRUB since I was going to add Ubuntu back.

Then I plugged in a flash drive with Ubuntu on it that I had used when I originally installed Ubuntu. I went to the boot menu of the laptop, clicked to make it boot from the flash drive, and it booted into GRUB.

However, it did not show the regular Ubuntu and Windows boot options; instead, it said

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

What can I do to get the device to boot into Windows so that I can delete GRUB and then reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93881/discussion-on-question-by-user440774-stuck-on-grub-bootloader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, while stuck in GRUB, I typed in `reboot` and hit enter. Then, as it was booting up (in my case, as it showed the Dell logo), I clicked F12 once and it showed options for Ubuntu and for Windows Boot Manager. I selected Windows Boot Manager, hit enter, and it booted into Windows. Then I signed in and followed the directions  in the first solution located [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/429610/447715). After following these directions, I rebooted it again to test it out. It worked; I did not see GRUB, and it booted directly into Windows.